# Pytube givng an "HTTP Error 404: Not Found" error. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, pytube

I'm having a problem trying to use the `pytube` package to download a video from YouTube.

I'm getting a `"HTTP Error 404: Not Found"` error. Is anyone familiar with this error? I've been trying to research about this but yet to find anything that causes the problem.

I will share my code and the error below:

```
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube("https://youtu.be/sflWFZKFJgk")

print(video.title)
print("downloading...")

video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()

print('Downloaded successfully!')
```

The error:

```
HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: upgrade to [pytube3](https://github.com/get-pytube/pytube3) and check

Comment: After uninstalling pytube and exiting the code editor and opened it again, I've then installed pytube3 and  still getting the same error mate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was [a known bug](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/990) with `pytube`.

`python -m pip install --upgrade pytube` it got fixed.

Comment: This worked! I was really trying to work with an alternative just in case the pytube didn't upgrade.

Comment: They are trying to figure it out. Its the known issue with pytube. I don't know the exact time when it will be fixed. You can follow the github issue page for quick update. https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1060

Answer (score 2):

Version 10.8.5 solves the problem. Upgrade with

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall the pytube

```
python -m pip uninstall pytube pytube3 pytubex
```

and install latest one

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone here was successful using the latest version of pytube.
I already did all steps of https://pypi.org/project/pytube/ and https://github.com/nficano/pytube but still with error _execute_request

Have you already tested it on Python 3.8.5?

Comment: @silverfox I don't think new contributors can leave comments under a question at an early stage when joining the community. So maybe that was his reason for it.

Comment: @Marcio Branco No I didn't tested it on Python 3.8.5. I'm currently using Python 3.9.5. Do you mind sharing the Traceback?

Comment: @MoiMyazz ahh, my mistake. No worries.