# getting Http error 404 in Pytube. What is reason for this?

Tags: python, youtube-api, http-error, pytube

[image: Error message/code]

This code used to work 4 days back now it is showing error. I tried using pytube3 but that does not help.

```
from pytube import YouTube** 
YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbBsqmKclXE').streams**
```

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbBsqmKclXE').streams

14 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)

```
647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
```

--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
650
651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: Is what you try to get available online? Can you see selected video in web browser?

Comment: yes. I am able to view in browser. you can check that too.

Comment: Is this even a valid YouTube API endpoint? Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/67615278/1841839

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytube givng an “HTTP Error 404: Not Found” error. Anyone knows how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67614883/6045800)

Comment: I had this problem, upgrading to 10.8.4 solved it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by [Ssuwani](https://github.com/Ssuwani). You can install `Pytube` from

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube
```

Comment: PyTube official release is also updated with the fix.

Comment: Error still persists with pytube==10.8.2.Tried ```http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsDtnTvgDB0``` if it helps to debug

Comment: This still doesn't work .

Comment: `pytube-10.8.5` got the fix

Comment: I am usung pytube 10.9.3 with python 3.9.5 on Windows 10 and this error occurs. Even after installing pytibe 10.8.5 doesvthe error persist.

Comment: Pytube 10.8.1
python 3.9.6
still getting the same error

Comment: Pytube 10.8.1 python 3.9.6 still getting the same error. Me too.

Comment: I tried Pytube 10.8.1 python 3.9.5 with this command, as well as pytube 10.9.3 with command `pip install pytube` but same error for both cases.

Comment: This issue is happening currently in pytube 10.9.3