# PYTUBE: raise HTTPerror (req.full_url, ....)

Tags: python, youtube-api, http-error, pytube

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYAeH.png)

And here is the code,

```
from pytube import YouTube 

#print(dir(pytube))

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BXJIjfJCsA&t=282s'
vdo = YouTube(url)

print(vdo.title)
print(vdo.thumbnail_url)
```

Though the url is correct, i get the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting Http error 404 in Pytube. What is reason for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616088/getting-http-error-404-in-pytube-what-is-reason-for-this)

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your pytube package, run your code again and it will work. The current version is 10.8.5

Go to your terminal and type in

```
pip install pytube --upgrade
```