# problem in printing a youtube title using python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling

**this was my code**

```
from pytube import YouTube
a=YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvpb8IdDZZI")
#to print title 
print("\n")
print("******************title*****************")
print("the title is:"+a.title)
```

**the error was**

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

but the url exists!!!and i have copied this url from browser itself
and i have also upgraded my pytube

Comment: You sure this is the code which is not working? It works for me.

Comment: Try updating pytube module [here](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used pytube, but the pafy module works fine for me, you can install it by writing the command "pip install pafy". Your code should look something like this:

```
import pafy

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvpb8IdDZZI"
video = pafy.new(url)

#to print title 
print("\n")
print("******************title*****************")
print("the title is:" + video.title)
```

You can find more information about the pafy module here: https://pypi.org/project/pafy/

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pytube with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube
```

And the official release has also fixed the problem.

You can get the deatils from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616088/getting-http-error-404-in-pytube-what-is-reason-for-this).

Comment: @Aravind Bhat hello friend, does it work?