# Download video from YouTube: HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, http, pytube

I use `pytube` to donwload video files from YouTube. The code was working fine, but recently started throwing `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`. How can I fix it? Or is there any other similar Python library that can be used to download videos from YouTube?

```
from pytube import YouTube

def downloadVideoFromYoutube(videourl, path):
    yt = YouTube(videourl)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension="mp4").order_by("resolution").desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    yt.download(path)
```

Error:

> /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in
> http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
> 648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
> 649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
> --> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> 651
> 652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
>
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I followed recommendations from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616088/getting-http-error-404-in-pytube-what-is-reason-for-this) but it did not work for me:

neither:

```
pip install pytube==10.8.5
```

nor:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube
```

nor:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Comment: @MDR: Yes, to the best of my knowledge. I'm running `10.9.3`.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment when I saw you updated the question.  Perhaps this is a [new bug](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1060).  Downing YT videos is always cat and mouse.

Comment: @MDR: I switched to "youtube_dl" and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda Environment May throw 'HTTP Error'. Run py code directly in cmd for example in windows :> python yourfilname.py

Comment: Thanks. I switched to "youtube_dl" and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with pytube, it has happened previously and got fixed but looks like it may have been reintroduced. You could always look into another library e.g. youtube_dl or ytpy or just try uninstalling pytube and install pytube3 instead.
(pip uninstall pytube)
(pip install pytube3)