# Pytube 404 not found

Tags: python, python-3.9, pytube

I just started getting this error with a known good url when I try to access the streams property of a YouTube object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\larso\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(video.streams)
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 321, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 214, in fmt_streams
    if "adaptive_fmts" in self.player_config_args:
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in player_config_args
    self._player_config_args = self.vid_info
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 291, in vid_info
    return dict(parse_qsl(self.vid_info_raw))
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 109, in vid_info_raw
    self._vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 53, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\larso\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This has only started happening recently, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: YouTube may have changed things on their end. Have you tried upgrading Pytube?

Comment: Could you share the code you ran that gets the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614883/pytube-givng-an-http-error-404-not-found-error-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-this i think you have same issue as in this link try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614883/pytube-givng-an-http-error-404-not-found-error-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-this rhis might help you